# Google utility to query or fix CSV (and XML, JSON, etc) files

Tags: json, csv

A while back I saw a project on code.google.com, created by Googlers, featuring a program that let you import a CSV file (or other delimited format), and then it very quickly let you query the file, or find distinct entries per column (and easily fix redundant data), etc.

I recall a video on youtube describing how to use the tool; I was impressed by her description. I recall she used the tool to import a big file from some government entity like park service, and then by finding the unique entries in each column she could see immediately which entries were mis-spelt / redundant / duplications of eachother, etc.

I believe the project was subsequently released as an open source app ... I just can't find it. Does anyone know what this is, and where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for OpenRefine. http://openrefine.org

Answer (score 0):

[CSVFix](http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/) possibly? Was recently moved from code.google.com to bitbucket.

Would something like https://github.com/rchowe/textsql help?